# Measuring intensity of a radio wave reflected from a metal plate

Tags: experimental-physics, distance-measurement, ultrasound, radio, transmission

[image]I am building a Project that can pinpoint location of a pen or any object (something as small as 0.5 mm radius sphere) placed on a flat screen.

I am using a ultrasound sensor (initially but i can switch to a different sensor if the situation demands) attached to one side of the flat screen ( on top edge). I'll be attaching a metal ( aluminium or copper) film on the object whose location I want to detect. I'll be using two ultrasound sensors to measure the x and y axis distance and pinpoint the location

I am trying to find a way wherein I can measure the intensity and direction of the reflected wave from the metal film to detect location. However I can't find a way to do so yet.

Is it possible to do so and if it is will ultrasound suffice ?

Comment: A schematic or photo helps

Comment: sure I'll add one asap.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad I have added an image (which i managed to draw on solidworks). I hope it clears any doubts related to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Typical distance sensors depend on time-of-flight.  If you're trying to hack the distance from return power level, you will not be happy (to put it mildly).  It's next to impossible to calibrate any system that way.

As to direction, it should be obvious that you cannot possibly do so with a single receiver. As a minimum you'd need two sensors aka two pixels, and then either compare the incoming phases (as done with radar) or the location of peak energy of a focussed input ( as is done with optics).

This is not a trivial problem .

Comment: I'm considering other options as well. The way I see it, intensity will vary a lot over the course of travel of the wave but I plan to get a receiver sensitive enough to measure even very low intensity wave. Direction is not the major problem as I have other ways to get it done.